# Java: printing file doesn't work

Tags: java, printing

I use Java 1.6 (JDK), Windows 7 and a virtual image printer driver.

I try to print some documents.

Here is my code

```
try {    

   System.out.println(" PrintServiceOverseer printFileToDefaultPrinter start "+ 
      fileName);            

   PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

   System.out.println(" default Printer " + printService.getName());

   FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));  

   DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;   

   Doc printDoc = new SimpleDoc(inputStream, docFlavor, null);

   PrintRequestAttributeSet  pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
   pras.add(new Copies(1));   

   DocPrintJob printJob = printService.createPrintJob();

   printJob.print(printDoc, pras);

   inputStream.close();    

   System.out.println(" PrintServiceOverseer printFileToDefaultPrinter end "); 
} catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it doesn't work. It prints nothing and no exception is thrown. The code compiles and runs smoothly, but there is no output.

Can you give me some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, I solved it by updating my printer's driver, I think you didn't install the proper driver, you may installed a driver which works for your printer but not the proper one.